# Copy and pasting link style sheet into the style class breaks link in vscode

Tags: html, css, button

hey so I want to copy and paste the code below into the 
  class but it breaks the link

i tried deleting the . before the /buttons_files/all.min.css"> but still doesnt work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/miles/Documents/buttons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./buttons_files/all.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" >
```

my expected results were it would work regardless of it were copy and pasted so long as the actual code is identical. Why does it break when in the style class?

Comment: Where is the buttons_files folder relative to your project root?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `button_files` folder located?
If you have removed the `.` before the filename make sure that the file directory listing does not start with `/`

Read more here for linking files outside of the root: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-link-files-in-a-different-folder

Read more here for detailed explanation to linking style sheets: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/htmlcss-linking

If it does not work could you provide a directory listing of your files?